# How to get values of input which has the same class as another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which renders `divs` as per the amount of results found in the search feature I have, and then In those `divs` I have hidden inputs with some information about the found user. One of the hidden inputs is the ID, What I want to happen is when the user clicks on the name label in any one of the `divs`, I want to save that hidden ID input field value to a variable using *jQuery*, so that I can use it as to determine what page to go to next by adding it in as a *param* in a url. I am using *jQuery*, *Twig* and *PHP*.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.search-result-name').click(function (){
        var lawyerId = $('.search-result-id').val();
        window.location.href = "/profile?lawyerId="+lawyerId;
    })      
})
```

```
<div class="search-result-info">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ item.id }}" class="search-result-id">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ item.verifiedLicense }}" class="search-result-id" id="verified-license">
    <div class="search-result-name">{{ item.firstName }} {{ item.lastName }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since it's not a direct answer to your question, I'd rather add an ID or a name attribute to each input and select the input using those:  `<input name="some-unique-name"... />` and `$('.search-result-id[name="some-unique-name"]')` or `<input id="some-unique-id"../>` and `$('#some-unique-id')`. It's easier to manage.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the approach by outputting the value you need to retrieve in the metadata of the `div` element. Then you can retrieve that value from the element reference in the event that's raised, something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.search-result-name').on('click', e => {
    const $element = $(e.target);
    var lawyerId = $element.data('lawyerid');
    
    console.log(`/profile?lawyerId=${lawyerId}`);
    // window.location.assign(`/profile?lawyerId=${lawyerId}`); // commented for this demo only, uncomment in production
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-result-info">
  <div class="search-result-name" data-lawyerid="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.firstName }} {{ item.lastName }}</div>
</div>
```

That being said, having a `div` be clickable and having it redirect to another page is not good practice. I would suggest you convert the HTML to use an `<a />` element, and output the data directly in to the `href` attribute. That way you don't need any JS at all:

```html
<div class="search-result-info">
  <a href="/profile?lawyerId={{ item.id }}" class="search-result-name">{{ item.firstName }} {{ item.lastName }}</a>
</div>
```